# capture mousedown event and get clientX and clientY in Mozilla

Tags: javascript

```
if (browserName == "Firefox")
{
   if (window.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN))
   {
      window.mousedown = load;
   }
}

function load(e)
{
   alert(e.clientX);
}
```

I want to mousedown on canvas and get `clientX` and `clientY`.
I'm doing it the above way but not getting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good example on how to get this feature.
http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-mouse-coordinates/

Here is a fiddle for that to play arround.
http://jsfiddle.net/straeger/tJ3nG/

Comment: in above jsbin i have two canvas tags when i mouse down on any then not getting clientX and clientY

Answer (score 0):

change `window.mousedown = load;` to `window.onmousedown = load;`

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because [`window.captureEvents`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.captureEvents) is obsolete. Use `addEventListener` instead.

Your event would look like this:

```
document.body.addEventListener("mousedown", load, false);
```

Comment: Not only that, it has been removed according to MDN, and does not return anything in Firefox 15 (and many, many versions before it), which means the `if` condition in the OP's post will never be true. Which means the actual `onmousedown` handler will never be invoked.

Comment: in above jsbin i have two canvas tags when i mouse down on any then not getting clientX and clientY